# How to loop through an array and execute a query within the loop in a store procedure in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I would like to embed a query in a stored procedure. The query to be embedded, however, is carried out within a `foreach` cycle because the values are transmitted from a form.

This is the snippet, in PHP:

```
<?php

foreach ($preferences as $preference) {

  $sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO preferences (preference, user_cod) values (:preference, :user_cod)');
  $sth->bindValue(':preference', $preference);
  $sth->bindValue(':user_cod', $user_cod);
  $sth->execute();

}

?>
```

How can I pass the array as a parameter to the stored procedure to execute the same query several times within the `foreach` loop in the stored procedure?

To give an example, the stored procedure would be structured like this:

```
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO users (name, surname) values (name_in, surname_in);

  INSERT INTO images (image, user_cod) values (image_name_in, user_cod_in);

  FOREACH preferences AS preference

    INSERT INTO preferences (preference, user_cod) values (preference_in, user_cod);

  END FOREACH;

END
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have arrays, there's no way to pass an array to a stored procedure. You could call the procedure from a PHP loop.

Comment: You could use a temporary table as a substitute for the array. Then join with the temporary table in the stored procedure.

Comment: How do I populate the temporary table if MySQL does not support arrays?

Comment: You do that in a PHP loop.

Comment: In your example code, you would normally have the prepare outside the loop.

Comment: So you suggest I create a temporary table in the PHP script, run the loop in the same script and then in the stored procedure query the temporary table by cycling the values?

Comment: *"So you suggest I create a temporary table in the PHP script, run the loop in the same script and then in the stored procedure query the temporary table by cycling the values"* Not necessarily. In most cases where you think you need a loop in sql, sql doesn't need a loop. E.g., if you already have your data in a temptable, just replace your loop by `INSERT INTO preferences (preference, user_cod) select preference, user_cod from temptable`. You could also consider just keeping the insert into the actual table in php (as in your current php code) instead of inserting into a temptable.

Comment: Preferences are selected from a form and passed on to the PHP script from the form. They are not pre-stored in a temporary table. So it would not make sense to add the preferences in a temporary table from the script and then migrate them to another table within the stored procedure. The insertion process would be duplicated. 
I guess I have no other alternative than to execute the loop outside the stored procedure and then in the PHP code.